# Php array replace 0 wth 00

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array which looks like this:

```
$a = [
  0 => "0",
  1 => "01",
  2 => "00",
]
```

I want to replace single zeros with two zeros.

should look like this:

```
[
  0 => "00",
  1 => "01",
  2 => "00",
]
```

I did this:

```
$newDigit = str_replace("0", "00", $splitDigit);
```

But it added everywhere 2 zeros:

```
[
  0 => "000",
  1 => "0001",
  2 => "0000",
]
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: Use `sprintf("%02d",$splitDigit);`

Comment: Use a formatting function like [sprintf()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach($arr as $str)
    $str = preg_replace('/^(0)$/', '00', $str);
```

or

```
foreach($arr as $str)
    if($str === '0')
            $str = '00';
```

or

`sprintf()` that is told.

Comment: missing $ at str = '00';

Comment: I just could not add something like this                 if($value === '\X') {
                 $value = '"';
                } do I have to loop it through another loop

Comment: `preg_replace()` will happily iterate an array.  The parentheses add no benefit in your pattern.

Answer (score 0):

[`sprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) is your friend:

```
$array = ["0", "01", "02"];

function doubleO($v){
    return(sprintf("%02d",$v));
}

$array = array_map("doubleO",$array);
print_r($array);
```

Outputs:

> Array ( [0] => 00 [1] => 01 [2] => 02 )

Comment: I'm not the op, but if I copy paste your code, I get `Array ( [0] => d [1] => d [2] => d )`

Comment: @FirstOne Then you've copied it incorrectly mate... Just tested it twice because you made me paranoid and it's definitely working. [Screenshot Link](http://i.imgur.com/YvfUx1s.png)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use do the replacement within a loop instead? 
Here:

```
<?php
        $arrDigits = [
                               0 => "0"
                               1 => "01"
                               2 => "00"
                              ];

        foreach($arrDigits as $key=>$strDigit){
            If ($strDigit == "0"){
                 $arrDigit[$key] = str_replace("0", "00", $strDigit);
            }
        }
        var_dump($arrDigits);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not do the replacement within a simple loop, instead?

```
<?php
        $arrDigits = [
                               0 => "0"
                               1 => "01"
                               2 => "00"
                              ];

        foreach($arrDigits as $key=>$strDigit){
            If ($strDigit == "0"){
                 $arrDigit[$key] = str_replace("0", "00", $strDigit);
            }
        }
        var_dump($arrDigits);
```